# Red filename in Ubuntu CLI (Vagrant)

Tags: css, ubuntu, vagrant, fuelphp, livereload

I am building a FuelPHP application running on an Ubuntu VM powered by Vagrant.

I am trying to include a CSS file on the global wrapper for all my pages, but Firebug tells me it isn't there. (the file path is correct in my <_link rel...>).

[image: Firebug]

The CSS file is actually a compiled from a bunch of LESS files using an app called LiveReload for Mac.

The Apache server on my VM is set to serve from a mounted folder on my Mac, anyone who has used Vagrant should know what I mean by that.

Anyway, LiveReload dumps the CSS file in the correct place, and is populated on my Mac:

[image: Mac]

However, SSHing into the VM and examining the CSS file leads me to believe that something weird is happening. Firstly, the filename is in red (but it exists!):

[image: red filename]

Secondly, opening it with a text editor (nano in this case) shows it to be blank, despite it being full on the Mac:

[image: blank]

So my question is... wtf is going on here? Why is it showing empty on the VM? Why is it red? Why can't Apache find and serve it?

EDIT, still struggling with this.

I added my own 'test.css' file and it loads that fine. Just not the app.css generated by LiveReload. There's something wrong on the VM. Can anyone help? It's one of those annoying things thats holding up my development.

Here's the stack trace (although i'm sure it has nothing useful in it):

[image: st]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, renamed the file to appcss.css instead of app.css and it works. Changed it back, it doesn't. System musn't like that name for some reason. Annoying the amount of time i wasted, but fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right than you have a wrong mod rewrite rule which redirects your request to a php script which tries to include a file which does not exists.

So check your .htaccess file

Comment: Thanks, I considered that but it's loading the JS files no problem, and they're in a similar location.

Comment: Is there some kind of stacktrace in that error page so that we can guess which php file makes the trouble?